# RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i am fetching data from webservices than i have to show this data in a recyclerView...i am setting my recyclerView in a onPostExecute of AsyncTask cuz i have to fetch data first.
Issue is that there is no View in my activity, every time i got this message...
here is my Main_activity...

```
    public class Store_Items_Display extends AppCompatActivity
    {
    public String s;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private DataAdapter dataAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_store__items__display);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
        dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(arrayList);
        Log.i("ArrayList  size :::", String.valueOf(arrayList.size()));
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        new Connection().execute();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            s = (String) bundle.get("userName");
            Log.i("Oncreate UserName ::: ", "Hamza");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.i("Data in intent ::;", "is Null");
        }

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        Button submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Toast.makeText(Store_Items_Display.this, "Submitted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }


    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StoreFirstActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        return true;
    }

    class Connection extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        final String TAG = "Items in ArrayList :::";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Toast.makeText(Store_Items_Display.this, "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            try
            {
                Log.i("User Name ::: ", "Hamza");
                URL url = new URL("http://10.0.3.2/FixItApp/GetData.php?user_name=khan"); // need changes here...
                HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(httpUrlConnection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    result.append(line);
                }
                in.close();
                reader.close();
                if (!result.toString().equals(""))
                {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result.toString());
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonObject.getString("user_data"));
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
                    {
                        String serial = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("serial_number");
                        String items = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("items");
                        String brand = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("brand");
                        String price = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("price");
                        arrayList.add(serial);
                        arrayList.add(items);
                        arrayList.add(brand);
                        arrayList.add(price);
                        Log.i(TAG, serial);
                        Log.i(TAG, arrayList.toString());
                        Log.i("ArrayList Size :::", String.valueOf(arrayList.size()));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Store_Items_Display.this, "No data found of this name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my DataAdapter Class...

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.MyViewHolder>
{
    private ArrayList<String> dataList;

    public DataAdapter(ArrayList<String> arrayList)
    {
        this.dataList = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.data_view, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        String items = dataList.get(position);
        holder.serial.setText(items);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
       return dataList.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView serial;
        public TextView items;
        public TextView brand;
        public TextView price;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            serial = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.serial);
            items = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.items);
            brand = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.brand);
            price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very confusing... Your onPostExecute returns `Void aVoid` ... So what arraylist are using in this line of code: `dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(arrayList);` in onPostExecute method? Your array list is empty ...?

Comment: i have pasted my full activity code ...

Comment: try moving this line : `new Connection().execute();`  after `dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(arrayList);` in `onCreate()` - this could be the issue.  However unless you're disabling screen rotation, evey time you rotate the screen you'll perform the AsyncTask? better to do a some logic like : `if (savedInstanceState == null)` or something similar.. also as previously pointed out, initialise your recycler view adapter once, and call `dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` when you change your arraylist data.

Comment: i still got this "RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout" error

Comment: Have you moved all your `RecyclerView` & `DataAdapter` initialisation into `onCreate();` - only call `dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` in `onPostExecute` ?

Comment: Post your updated code ..

Comment: Remove this line `recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);` that should fix the problem.  You're saying that you want the adapter to have zero items (your initial array list is empty), and keep that size fixed, even if you invalidate the data and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: the problem is still not fixed, i got no View in my activity

Comment: What is the size of the arraylist when you call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: the size of anArraylist is 4

Comment: issue is solved,  i have implement recyclerView inside scrollView in my  layout, after removing scollView everything works fine. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The code is bad in couple of ways. If you set new adapter each time you fetch the data then there's no point for `notifyDataSetChanged()` call. But in fact what you should be rather do instead is **replace the data**, not the adapter and then simply call `dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` on existing adapter to let it know data has changed.

Comment: i have undestand your answer but after removing notifyDataSetChanged() i still got that msg and still got no View in my activity...

Comment: You should set up your recycler view in onCreate/onCreateView. If you got no data, then your adapter will be "empty". But it will be there and recycler will not complain. Also I'd suggest removing creating new adapters instead.

Comment: i have initialize my recyclerView in onCreate, but i can't set up recyclerView in onCreate, i have to wait for webService response...

Comment: What is the reason you cannot init your recycler view with **empty** dataset?

Comment: my recyclerView is showing nothing why? that a i need to know, i have done what you asked me.